# how to get a value when <input value> is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a donation form and I've have created an editable donation total on my site. I need to copy the value from this box to the plugin donation total so when the form is submitted the plugin's value is used. 
I've used javascript to copy over the value and it is working:

```
var p = '£' + price;
$('#ffm-total').val(p);
var hiddenTotal = document.getElementById("give-final-total-wrap").getElementsByClassName("give-final-total-amount")[0];
hiddenTotal.innerHTML = p;
```

However, I also need the price to be editable. 
I've got the field:

```
<label class="give-label give-fl-label" for="ffm-total">Total</label>
<input class="textfield give-fl-input fill_inited filled" id="ffm-total" type="text" data-required="no" data-type="text" name="total" placeholder="Total" value="" data-value="£5199">
<p id="give-final-total-wrap" class="form-wrap ">
            <span class="give-donation-total-label">
        Donation Total:     </span>
    <span class="give-final-total-amount" data-total="18">
        £18     </span>
        </p>
```

and I tried to use:

```
var finalTotal = document.getElementById("#ffm-total");  
var hiddenTotal = document.getElementById("give-final-total-wrap").getElementsByClassName("give-final-total-amount")[0];
hiddenTotal.innerHTML = finalTotal;
```

But it does not work. Although the value is editable it does not save the value in the  rather in the 'data-value' so `finalTotal.value` does give any value. 
How do I get the value and use it to populate the hiddenTotal?
You can see the issue here: [site with issue](http://future.wordpressdeveloper.uk/gyalumni/sponsorship/)

Comment: try this `var finalTotal = document.getElementById("ffm-total");  
`

Comment: This may not be the issue, but as Naveed Ramzan noted you should not include # when using `getElementById()`, so, rather than `document.getElementById("#ffm-total");`, it should be `document.getElementById("ffm-total");`.

Comment: right, sorry, it was a typo. It isn't working like that either

Answer (score 1):

Inside `getElementById` you don't need to use `#` with the `id` and the value is set using `.value` not `.innerHTML`

```js
var finalTotal = document.getElementById("ffm-total");  
var hiddenTotal = document.getElementById("give-final-total-wrap");
finalTotal.onkeyup=function(){
hiddenTotal.value = finalTotal.value;
}
```

```html
<label class="give-label give-fl-label" for="ffm-total">Total</label>
<input class="textfield give-fl-input fill_inited filled" id="ffm-total" type="text" data-required="no" data-type="text" name="total" placeholder="Total" value="" data-value="£5199">
<input id='give-final-total-wrap'>
```

Comment: you added onkeyup="a()" to the code. How would I add this using javascript to the <input>. I can't edit the plugin code.

Comment: @LTech check the edits

Comment: finalTotal.value does not give a value. Please look at the link to my site, there is not value set in the input field